# Unexpected error while Controller unit test

Tags: rest, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I am learning unit testing. I have implemented unit test for the spring boot controller in my sample project. When I run the test class, every time it returns 400 status (Expected 200). After i did a research and I have found that `if(entity.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {` is line which gives exception. It might be because it uses return of Service2.

However, code is working fine without running test cases. I have attached MyController and MyControllerTest classes.

**My Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
@Autowired
private UserManagementService userManageService;
@Autowired
private AdminManagementService adminManageService;
@Autowired
private AuthenticateManagementService authService;

@PutMapping("/change-password")
public ResponseEntity<?> changePassword(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, 
        @RequestBody PasswordChangeRequestDTO passwordChangeRequestDTO) {
    ResponseDTO finalResponse = new ResponseDTO();
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Changing user password.");
        KeycloakLoginResponseDTO keycloakResponse = authService.auhtenticate(passwordChangeRequestDTO.getLoginRequestDTO());
        ResponseEntity<?> logoutEntity = authService.logout(token, keycloakResponse.getSession_state());
        if(logoutEntity.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            LOGGER.info("User password matched");
        }
        String userId = adminManageService.getUserByName(token, passwordChangeRequestDTO.getLoginRequestDTO().getUsername());
        ResponseEntity<?> entity = userManageService.changePassword(token, passwordChangeRequestDTO, userId);
        LOGGER.info("USER : " + "" +"has successfully changed password.");
        finalResponse.setMessageCode(HttpStatus.OK);
        finalResponse.setMessage("Password changed successfully");
        finalResponse.setError(false);
        ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> finalEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().body(finalResponse);
        return finalEntity;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("Error has occured while changing password of USER : " + "" + ".");
        finalResponse.setMessageCode(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        finalResponse.setMessage("Oops! Looks like you have entered the wrong password in the 'Old Password' field");
        finalResponse.setMessageDetail(e.getMessage());
        finalResponse.setError(true);
        ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> finalEntity = ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(finalResponse);
        return finalEntity;
    }
}
}
```

**Controller Unit test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private UserManagementService userManageService;
@MockBean
private AdminManagementService adminManageService;
@MockBean
private AuthenticateManagementService authService;

@InjectMocks
private UserController userController;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testChangePasswordhappyPath() throws Exception {
    PasswordChangeRequestDTO passwordChangeRequestDTO = new PasswordChangeRequestDTO();
    LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO = new LoginRequestDTO();
    loginRequestDTO.setClient_id("test_client");
    loginRequestDTO.setGrant_type("test_grant_type");
    loginRequestDTO.setPassword("test_password");
    loginRequestDTO.setUsername("test_user");
    CredentialsRequestDTO credentialsRequestDTO = new CredentialsRequestDTO();
    credentialsRequestDTO.setTemporary(false);
    credentialsRequestDTO.setType("password");
    credentialsRequestDTO.setValue("test_password");
    passwordChangeRequestDTO.setLoginRequestDTO(loginRequestDTO);
    passwordChangeRequestDTO.setCredentialsRequestDTO(credentialsRequestDTO);

    ResponseEntity<String> mockResponse = new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    when(userManageService.changePassword("Token", passwordChangeRequestDTO, "UserId")).thenReturn(mockResponse);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(passwordChangeRequestDTO);

    mockMvc.perform(put("/user/change-password", passwordChangeRequestDTO)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization", "Token")
            .content(json)
            .characterEncoding("utf-8"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong here. Is there anything to add to my `MyControllerTest` class or How can i cover this test case. Any help would be grateful.

**UPDATED**

I have also added `e.printStackTrace()`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycode.controller.UserController.changePassword(UserController.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:919)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
at com.mycode.controller.UserControllerTest.testChangePasswordhappyPath(UserControllerTest.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: Your test only stubs `service1.method2()`. But your code never calls `service1.method2()`. It only calls `service1.method1()` and `service2.method2()`. So the call to service2.method2() returns null, so entity.getStatusCode() throws a NullPointerException. You need to tell the mocked beans what to  return when they're called.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry my mistake. It is not the problem. I have updated the question.

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile. Post code that compiles. Add `e.printStackTrace()` to your catch block, and read the stack trace to know which error is thrown from where.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank for the response. yes it is a NullPointerException. How can i get rid of this?

Comment: Again, by analyzing the stack trace, adding println() in your code, or using your debugger to know *what* is null and thus causing the exception to be thrown. Then act accordingly to fix the issue.

Comment: @JBNizet I have alread tried.. Please find updated stack trace. There is no route cause.

Comment: The root cause **is** the NullPointerException. At line 39 of UserController.java, something is null. I have no idea of which line that is. You should be able to know that.

Comment: @JBNizet `ResponseEntity<String> entity = service2.method2();` is line. My question was how can i find a solution for this when writing unit test.

Comment: So that means that service2 is null. Which I don't see how it would be possible with the fake code you posted. If you want help, post the real code.

Comment: The code you posted apparently doesn't seem to be the actual code, but a slimmed down version. There is half of a method signature in there, so it wouldn't even compile. I wonder what else is missing or left out for things that are actually important for the test/controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes I have slimmed it down for the simplicity. I'll upload the real code.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated

Comment: Can you clarify which line fails?

Comment: @M.Deinum In Controller `if(logoutEntity.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {` this is the line. Because it uses returning object from the service. How can i avoid this

Comment: Then your mock setup is wrong, your predicate doesn't match and hence the default is to return `null`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please guide me

Comment: You have registered `userManageService.changePassword("Token", passwordChangeRequestDTO, "UserId")` in your `when`. however this doesn't match. So either it isn't `Token` or `UserId` or you haven't implementted equals and hashcode in your`PasswordChangeRequestDTO` which makes it fail.

Comment: You should also register behavior for the call to `adminManageService.getUserByName` currently you haven't and it will return `null`. `null` doesn't match `UserId`.

Comment: @ M. Deinum I tried, but getting same error. I have registered all the service methods

Comment: @M.Deinum `when(authService.auhtenticate(loginRequestDTO)).thenReturn(keycloakLoginResponseDTO);
  when(authService.logout("Token", keycloakLoginResponseDTO.getSession_state())).thenReturn(mockLogoutResponse);
  when(userManageService.changePassword("Token", passwordChangeRequestDTO, mockUserId)).thenReturn(mockResponse);
  when(adminManageService.getUserByName("Token", passwordChangeRequestDTO.getLoginRequestDTO().getUsername())).thenReturn(mockUserId);`

Comment: Don't add code as comments, that becomes unreadable. Somewhere you expectations/predicates don't match, leading to `null` answers. As stated make sure you have implemented a proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementation for the `PasswordChangeRequestDTO` as apparently that is part of a method call as well.